# Natural Language Processing (NLP) in .net environment

Tags: nlp, .net

I'm developing a project on .net (using web API and MVC). now I have to add another module which users can make queries of Data we have in the DB and retrieve the relevant answer.

- Is their a easy way to Do NLP developments in .net
- If yes, It would be a great help if someone can give a brief idea on how to get started

any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The purpose of this question was to get an advice from someone who was in the same situation as I am right now. Sorry if my question offended anyone. I found a starting point to this and I'm following those steps now. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like for my requirement  [**Stanford CoreNLP**](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) would do the trick. and there are so many services provided by **azure** for the same purpose. Sorry if my question offended someone in any way.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of NLP libraries for .Net if you Google that. Please be more specific as to what you want to accomplish when they query the DB.

Comment: Dear @CalZ Thank you for your answer. yes I googled this but some points are not clearly mentioned and there was no any documentations to those also. so can you please suggest me of a good site and a documentation to refer. That would be a big help for me with the situation i'm in now.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you want to accomplish when they query the DB.